# Receiving Image-UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-universal

I m using VS 2017, and I need to receive Image form other app. So its basically App-App Communication. I m new in UWP and windows mobile developing, so I research a lot, and I manage to get DataPackage with shared content.

When you try to examine this:

```
if (this.shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
{
    this.sharedBitmapStreamRef = await this.shareOperation.Data.GetBitmapAsync();

    //catch (Exception ex)
    //{
    //    NotifyUserBackgroundThread("Failed GetBitmapAsync - " + ex.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    //}
}
```

Problem is that app doesn't see my file as Bitmap.
When I try to get type of recived file it gives me System.__COMObject.
I manage get file as storageitem, but I cannot read IRandomAccessStreamReference.
As StorageItem I get, path, name etc.

The same thing is happening on ShareTarget example app, its also doesn't see image as BitMap(formatId). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: So why not load the StorageItem to a BitmapImage?

Comment: Does the ShareSource use the `DataPackage.SetBitmap` method to set the bitmap image contained in the DataPackage? If so,  the ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap) will return `true`. You can also check what is the StandardDataFormats type.

Comment: @IgorKulman    I share data from gallery or File Explorer.I manage to load BitmapImage by reading Path from IStorageItem, then creating a StorageFIle. My next problem is that it only works if the file is in Pictures(internal storage)folder. I also add possibility to open pdf. and it opens when .pdf file is in picture folder. I m now looking what permissions i need and how to implement File Type Associations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its break on this line StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath); with this exeption +  $exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at App1.MainPage.<File_Stream>d__12.MoveNext()

Comment: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()} System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Answer (score 0):

Refer this sample https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-share-data-between-6ef0a355 on msdn.

Target app:

```
if (operation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
{
    shareType.Text = "Bitmap";
    shareTitle.Text = operation.Data.Properties.Title;
    imgShareImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    tbShareData.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    RandomAccessStreamReference imageStreamRef = await operation.Data.GetBitmapAsync();
    IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType streamWithContentType = await imageStreamRef.OpenReadAsync();
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(streamWithContentType);
    imgShareImage.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: I build that project right now and it doesn't recognize bitmap, just break all shareoperations statements, without output, its important that i need this to work on windows phone

Comment: I receive .pdf or image objects as system_combobject, and it only recognize it as storage item. I use to create storage file, from path.